# How to get a list of all the fonts currently available for Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

e.g. when I want to set `font` in

```
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
```

Comment: Apparently none of these will list the fonts available in the `mpl-data` directory found in `~/anaconda/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf` (try `import matplotlib; matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()` to get the exact location). Despite the fact that **using `fname=<font>` to load fonts in this location is sucessful**. Does anyone have an answer that will do so?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')
```

Check [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/font_manager_api.html) for other options.

Comment: Also, the arguments specified are the defaults, so `matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts()` returns the same thing.

Comment: Any idea how to get the names of the installed font-families instead of the single files?

Answer (score 33):

To get a (readable) list of fonts available to `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
flist = matplotlib.font_manager.get_fontconfig_fonts()
names = [matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname=fname).get_name() for fname in flist]
print names
```

The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.get_fontconfig_fonts) recommends `get_fontconfig_fonts()`:

> This is an easy way to grab all of the fonts the user wants to be made
>   available to applications, without needing knowing where all of them
>   reside.

Note that you can get the (inverse) name to font lookup easily by using the `FontProperties` class:

```
font = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(family='TeX Gyre Heros')
file = matplotlib.font_manager.findfont(font)
```

`findfont` is robust as it returns a default font if it can't find matching properties.

Comment: Neat, thanks. Looks like this one gives the actual **callable names** while the accepted answer shows the actual `.ttf` files. Unfortunately for whatever reason **this fails on my macbook (MacOS Sierra)**, but works on some remote Linux servers I use. The accepted answer works everywhere.

Comment: Gives error "RuntimeError: In FT2Font: Can not load face. Unknown file format."

Comment: Returns empty list Python 3.8.3 + matploblib 3.3.2

Comment: matplotlib.font_manager.get_fontconfig_fonts()
C:\QGB\Anaconda3\Scripts\ipython:1: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The get_fontconfig_fonts function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.5 and will be removed two minor releases later.
Out[178]: []

Comment: This works if you just replace `get_fontconfig_fonts()` with `findSystemFonts()`

Answer (score 28):

Per [this blog post](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/data-studio/matplotlib/list-all-fonts-available-in-matplotlib-plus-samples/), this code will get you fonts available and samples:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
from IPython.core.display import HTML

def make_html(fontname):
    return "<p>{font}: <span style='font-family:{font}; font-size: 24px;'>{font}</p>".format(font=fontname)

code = "\n".join([make_html(font) for font in sorted(set([f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist]))])

HTML("<div style='column-count: 2;'>{}</div>".format(code))
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me in Google Colab as least. It seems Matplotlib fonts aren't necessarily available outside of Matplotlib maybe?

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer provides only a list of *paths* to fonts on your machine, but not the font *name* that you can pass to `rcParams`. @Alodi's answer addresses this point, but is outdated.

In Python 3.8.8 with Matplotlib 3.3.4, you can use the following:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
fpaths = matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts()

for i in fpaths:
    f = matplotlib.font_manager.get_font(i)
    print(f.family_name)
```

It prints a list of font names:

```
Padauk Book
Laksaman
Waree
Umpush
Latin Modern Roman Demi
Tlwg Mono
Gubbi
...
```

Comment: As of 2022 this should be the accepted answer.  BTW, jeez I have a lot of fonts...

Comment: When I run this I get a lot of duplicates. I got a more useful list by adding the fonts to a set and then printing the set after the loop. That has the added benefit of sorting the list.

Answer (score 10):

#### New in matplotlib 3.6.0

There is now a helper method **[`get_font_names()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontManager.get_font_names())** to list all available fonts:

```
from matplotlib import font_manager
font_manager.get_font_names()
```

Note that the resulting list won't be alphabetical. That's fine if you're just checking something programmatically, but if you're checking visually, sort alphabetically for easier scanning:

```
sorted(font_manager.get_font_names())

# ['Advent Pro',
#  'Anonymous Pro',
#  ...
#  'DejaVu Sans',
#  'DejaVu Sans Mono',
#  'DejaVu Serif',
#  ...
#  'Noto Mono',
#  'Noto Sans',
#  'Noto Serif',
#  ...
#  'Roboto',
#  'Roboto Flex',
#  'Roboto Mono',
#  'Roboto Serif',
#  ...
#  'TeX Gyre Adventor',
#  'TeX Gyre Bonum',
#  'TeX Gyre Chorus',
#  'TeX Gyre Cursor',
#  'TeX Gyre Heros',
#  'TeX Gyre Pagella',
#  'TeX Gyre Schola',
#  'TeX Gyre Termes',
#  ...
#  'Ubuntu',
#  'Ubuntu Mono']
```