# Available "font-family" entry for draw_networkx_labels

Tags: ubuntu, matplotlib, networkx, font-family

I have this code:

```
    labels_params = {"labels":{n: "" if n[0] == "." else n for n in G.nodes () },
                     "font_family":"sans-serif",
                     "alpha":.5,
                     "font_size":16 }

    draw_networkx_labels (G, pos, **labels_params)
```

My problem is that I wish to be able to display in my output graph more than 2 fonts .

I wish to know how can I detect all possible entries for "font_family".

I browsed the code of FontManager from Networkx, and I see only "sans-serif".

I am working in X11 under Ubuntu.

Comment: As I understand it, networkx uses matplotlib for most of its drawing. Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18962217/1643946) help identify what fonts you have available on your system?  Matplotlib typically has several families available -- as illustrated in [this demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fonts_demo.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, it does not help :( . This is the man page of draw_labels: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_labels.html -- It does not have any parameter "fontname", but only fontfamily. My question is about setting node labels, not about setting the title ... :(

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fonts_demo.html <= This page is closer of what I want. It provides a list of fontfamilies accepted by draw_labels. My question is what it the complete list, and how can I see in the system what are the available families...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Poking around a bit in the `draw_networkx_labels` source, it does indeed come down to a call to `ax.text` (where ax is a matplotlib axis).  So that means you should have as much configurability as you get with any normal MPL text ([docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text)).

### Font names vs font families

As far as I can tell, a font name is an instance of a font family; though because
the generic families (eg 'serif') are often given as settings to font family 
variables.   http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

This has confused me for a while, so please correct me if I'm wrong here.

## Finding the full list of fonts

So if you use the technique from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18821968/1643946):

```
avail_font_names = [f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist]
```

you get all the (specific) options.  Don't know where you find a fuller list than
the [font demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fonts_demo.html) for generics.

this post shows a method for [searching by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962063/matplotlib-setting-title-bold-while-using-times-new-roman/18962217#18962217):

```
[i for i in matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf') if 'times' in i.lower()]
```

## Using more than one font for labels in your graph

From the `avail_font_names` list above, I picked out three for this example; you might have to substitute some of them depending on what you have installed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

font_names = ['Sawasdee', 'Gentium Book Basic', 'FreeMono', ]
family_names = ['sans-serif', 'serif', 'fantasy', 'monospace']


# Make a graph
G  = nx.generators.florentine_families_graph()

# need some positions for the nodes, so lay it out
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# create some maps for some subgraphs (not elegant way)
subgraph_members  = [G.nodes()[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(G.nodes()), 3)]

plt.figure(1)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)


for i, nodes in enumerate(subgraph_members):
    f = font_names[(i % 3)]
    #f = family_names[(i % 4)]
    # extract the subgraph
    g = G.subgraph(subgraph_members[i])
    # draw on the labels with different fonts
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos, font_family=f, font_size=40)

# show the edges too
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)


plt.show()
```

[image: example figure showing different font labelling]

### Resolving the 'Falling back to ...' warnings

Note: if you get errors when of the form "UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to ...", when trying to use fonts even if they do exist, this [nabble dialog](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Fonts-not-found-td12936.html) suggests clearing the font cache: (*yup, this will irretrievably remove a file* but it is auto-generated.)

```
rm ~/.matplotlib/fontList.cache
```

Comment: Any comment is too much ! Thank you ! Thank you !

Comment: You happened to ask on the day where I also needed to resolve a very similar font problem ;) Glad it is of use.

Comment: how can I get an arabic fonts working? which font family should I use?