# python matplotlib after upgrade changed latex font

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, latex

Before upgrading my matplotlib library (macOS), I had the following latex font in my figure's texts : [image]

However after the update, I am getting the following font: [image]

In both codes, i am using the following command: 
`plt.title(r'$L_x = 1\mathrm{m}, \ \phi_{in}=1$')`.
Can you please help me get the back the font of the first figure?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MathText](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) has its own fontset. You can set it via the [`rcParam`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) `mathtext.fontset`.

```
#mathtext.fontset : dejavusans ## Should be 'dejavusans' (default),
                               ## 'dejavuserif', 'cm' (Computer Modern), 'stix',
                               ## 'stixsans' or 'custom'
```

To get a serif MathText, use, `dejavuserif`, `cm`, or `stix`.

Example

```
plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = "stix"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines before your plot

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

You may have to dig a bit to find the correct font though, maybe your original one was not 'sans-serif'.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I got the following error: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex'

Comment: Do you have latex installed on your computer ? You can see that, typing `which latex` in a terminal.
Anyway, you can then just remove my last proposed line (hence, remove `rc('text', usetex=True)` .

Comment: Yes I have tex live installed on my mac, however when I type 'which latex' in the terminal I dont get an output.  Also when I remove the line you mentioned i get the following error: UserWarning: findfont: Font family [u'sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

Comment: mmmmh this is weird. The update probably broke something with latex and/or matplotlib. I see two main options (1) the code I gave without the last line works, but cannot find the font 'sans-serif', you can try to find one that works (maybe 'helvetica', 'times new roman', ...) (2) try to reinstall latex and see if that fixes the problem with or without my code.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8755818/3283333) an interesting answer to check which fonts are available for matplotlib.

Comment: will check them, seems interesting