# use font 'Times New Roman' for all plt plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I want to use the font 'Times New Roman' for my matplotlib plots.
I tried the command:

> `import matplotlib as mpl`
>
> `mpl.rcParams["font.family"] = "serif"`
>
> `mpl.rcParams["font.serif"] = "Times New Roman"`

When I just use these lines, it is fine.

But when I want to create a plot. For example a piechart with a title.

> `plt.pie(data, ...)`
>
> `plt.title('Piechart')`
>
> `plt.show()`

It get this Error:

> WARNING:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: Generic family 'serif' not found because none of the following families were found: Times New Roman

Can you please explain to me what I am doing wrong and which steps I need to take.

Comment: Your Times might have a slightly different name. You might try to check all available fonts first [How to get a list of all the fonts currently available for Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753835/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-fonts-currently-available-for-matplotlib)